# How to Autoload Chromium Php Library

Tags: php, zend-framework, composer-php, autoload, google-chrome-headless

Good day,
Please I just downloaded the headless Chromium php library, yes this is a problem I face with other libs as well. I have been coding with php and have gotten good at it, however, I use raw php in zend framework and I do not know how to Autoload a library.

After, downloading, I included the browserFactory class but there are other dependencies and it throws an error, that so and so class not found. I keep including but then it needs another and there are so many.

Please, is there a way around this. How do I include all files in directory or Autoload all classes?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can use [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) that manage dependencies in PHP. And this is what is recommended from [library doc](https://github.com/chrome-php/headless-chromium-php#install)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to autoload classes, you have to use composer. You can install PHP Chromium library by running this command:

```sh
composer require chrome-php/chrome
```

Then, in your main PHP file (in Zend would be `public/index.php`), add this line:

```php
require 'path/to/vendor/autoload.php';
```

Finally, you can use library's classe just by importing them:

```php
// With USE declaration
use HeadlessChromium\BrowserFactory;
$browserFactory = new BrowserFactory();

// Or without the USE declaration
$broswerFactory = new HeadlessChromium\BrowserFactory();
```

Comment: Would have asked how to install composer but let me not bore you, I'll Google it. Thanks again

Comment: @ChidiebereOnwunyirigbo take a look at [composer's documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-linux-unix-macos)